# Keeping timer events equally spaced

Tags: java, swing, timer, consistency

I'm attempting to get an animation working in a game I'm developing. The animation works by setting a button size to very small, then gradually growing it to its normal size again. I have it working, except I'm having timing issues.

Sometimes the button will grow almost instantly, sometimes it goes VERY slow. I'm looking for something inbetween, and I need it to ALWAYS grow at that size, not some times fast sometimes slow.

I've looked into it and I found this pseudocode:

```
distance_for_dt = speed * delta_time
new_position = old_position + distance_for_dt
```

Unfortunately I don't understand what's being said, and I don't know how to apply this to my code. Can anyone help with that or explain what's being said in the above pseudocode?

Here's my timer code, `timer` is already defined above as a `Timer`, and z[] is just a pair of coordinates:

```
timer = new Timer(18, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Dimension dim = button[z[0]][z[1]].getSize();
                if (dim.getHeight() < 79.9) {
                    button[z[0]][z[1]].setSize((int) (dim.getWidth() + 6), (int) (dim.getHeight() + 6));
                } else {
                    button[z[0]][z[1]].setSize(80, 80);
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
```

Comment: `Sometimes the button will grow almost instantly, sometimes it goes VERY slow.` - I've never noticed this behaviour. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Here is an example, the effect is much less notable in this version then mine, but I think thats because my application has more stuff going on in the background http://pastebin.com/MNqsXAiD

Comment: Make sure you are asking repaint at the end of the adtionPerformed method

Comment: *"Here is an example"..*  You were advised to post an SSCCE, rather than uncompilable code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many updates you're calling on your Swing application, it may be getting "backed up" and slowing down.  For instance, if you wanted to accomplish the animation without a Timer, you could just do something like this:

```
// example method to do animation
public void animateButton(final int wait){
    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            // some loop structure to define how long to run animation
            Dimension dim = button[z[0]][z[1]].getSize();
            while (dim.getHeight() < 79.9){
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
                        //update Swing components here
                    });
                    try{ Thread.Sleep(wait); }
                    catch(Exception e){}
                }
            }
        }
    }
    thread.start();
}
```

I think this may be similar to how a Timer updates the GUI, as Timers run on a separate thread.  I would look into whether or not you need to use `invokeLater(new Runnable)` inside a `timer` to properly schedule the task.  I had to do this to allow a project I was working on to keep responsive during long tasks.  If you really needed to ensure the speed and maybe DROP updates to adjust for system lag, then you'll need to be calculating how complete the animation is vs how much time has passed, using a method call such as `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `System.nanoTime()`.  Then, adjust accordingly for each step of the animation.